# Label Propagation Algorithm in spark vs neo4j

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

i have graph data about 9M node and 120M edge

i ran the lpa algorithm on apache-spark with 2gb heap-size and after about 6 hours the algorithms stop due to memory limitation

so... i ran the same algorithm on the same data but from neo4j with 3gb of heap size
and it's give me the results after about 1 hour

my question is why in this case neo4j is much faster and memory effective than spark ?
as i know spark is good for mid2big data problems where as neo4j good for small2mid size data problems

Comment: how come you know that neo4j is good for small2mid size data problems? The only difference I see is that spark is distributed where Neo4j is not.

Comment: Another thing to note is that there the default setting in Neo4j is max 10 iterations of LPA, so it might finish before it converges. I don't know the default behavior for Spark though